# SqlException: Login failed for user (user is not the set user in the connection string)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have built a website using asp.net core 2.1 which works fine on my local machine. However, when I upload the published files to the hosting (1&1 shared windows hosting if it matters at all) I get the following error message

```
SqlException: Login failed for user 'WINHOST\WINSHUK104BS$'.
```

I have a connection string in my appsettings.json which looks like:

```
    {
  "Data": {
    "GWebBlog": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=db778661550.hosting-data.io;Database=db778661550;User id=db778661550;Password=[password-omitted];Trusted_Connection=True;"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea as to what on earth is going on? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time and expertise, I look forward to your response

******* EDIT ******

I updated the connection string as suggested. However, I have the same error message but the right user.

```
SqlException: Login failed for user 'db778661550'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, object providerInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)
```

Comment: You should use either Trusted_Connection(Windows authentication) or the username password(SQL Server authentication).

Comment: Hi @ChiragK, thank you for your suggestion. I have implemented it but still having the same (or similar) issue. I have updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use both `User id / password` and `Trusted Connection`. Pick one - if you want to use the specified user id, typical for a website (though there are exceptions), then remove the trusted connection attribute. See the first two examples [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

"Trusted connection" sounds like the thing you always want to have (who wants a connection you can't trust?), but what this property actually means is *use Windows Authentication* to pass the credentials of the current user. This is *possible* for a web site, but not common, especially for a blog.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for answering my question. I have made the change you suggested however i still get a sql exception. I have updated the question with details. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @M_Griffiths Well, getting closer, but now it just sounds like the SQL Authentication password is incorrect. You can check for sure what went wrong during the login attempt by looking at the message and state number in the error log (see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456) for reference). The error message the client gets is vague on purpose - obscuring the reason behind the error is much more secure than giving a potential attacker more direct guidance on how they're failing.

Comment: Thank you, you've saved my butt lol. I had missed a letter in my username. Something so simple, yet caused a fair amount of swearing lol. Thanks again, much appreciated.